# Analyzing packets in android

Tags: networking, 3g, logging

I want to analyze packets on my rooted Android mobile phone.

#### What I did so far:

I have installed shark for root and shark reader. I tried to sniff packets, but shark reader only shows RAW packet.

What do I need in order to be able analyze packets of applications in my phone? Do I need to install tcpdump alongside with shark for root?

P.S: I use 3G internet only.

Comment: Another good app for network discovery is Fing, while it doesnt provide packet information, it does give you each host and hostname with ping/tracert and a few options more. Good to use in combination with wifinspect or packetshark.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the very first line on [Google Play for Shark Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lv.n3o.sharkreader)

> Application for reading pcap files.

Which implies the OP needs some tool to generate pcap files..also, reading this also on [Google Play for Shark for root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lv.n3o.shark)

> *Traffic sniffer, works on 3G and WiFi (works on FroYo tethered mode too). To open dump use WireShark or similar software, for preview dump
>   on phone use Shark Reader. **Based on tcpdump**. Please leave
>   comments/send e-mail if you have any problems/suggestions.*

Bolded sentence is my emphasis, so it seems a bit confusing and mis-leading. From the description on the Play Store, it is saying that using **WireShark** is a pre-requisite for Shark Reader to work..but cannot find the actual app called the same.

There is one available for desktop PC's to allow sniffing of ethernet traffic, but for Android, remains to be seen.

Also, for what its worth, sniffing traffic on 3G is questionable as that's dependent on if the radio base-band allows promiscuous mode, that's a given in order to be able to sniff traffic, even though its unlikely, due to proprietary nature of radio firmware..)

Wifi on the other hand, is extremely dependent of the capability of sniffing also, not all of them have the capability to go into promiscuous mode, again mileage will vary depending on the Wifi chipset/driver and kernel regardless if rooted.

Answer (score 1):

You could try 
[WiFinspect [Root]](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.opticiancms.wifiprobe) or
[PacketShark](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=edu.droidshark). Both have buildin package analyse features.

As far as i know, package sniffing is only possible for wifi.

Comment: Another nice possiblity is remote analysing your packages with wireshark as descriped [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/analyzing-android-network-traffic/)

Comment: You've left three answers here, all suggesting these two apps. Do you have an affiliation with either or both? If so, [you need to disclose](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) that in your answers. If not, it looks awfully spammy.

Comment: torayoff asked, what he need to analyse packages within his phone. both tools provide this feature without needing any aditional stuff. i'm not affiliated with any of them. This site only supports to link 2 of them. i think These both are the best of all i know. Possible all 3 questions should be merged!?

Comment: They are free apps. I don't think that OP is affiliated with them. Looks like a valid and correct answer to me, since I also would recommend the same apps.